# Strange Breakpoint behavior in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4

I am writing a tutorial about the new Xcode and in my project I have these two very simple lines of code.

```
int a = 5;
a = a + 6; // Breakpoint in this line
```

I have a breakpoint on the second line of code and to my understanding a breakpoint always stop the program **before** the selected line is executed. So *a* is 5;

I played a bit with *Step Into* and *Step out* and later on when I ran the program again *a* was 11! The debugger stopped at the same line but the code was already executed.

I closed Xcode 4 and started it again and all was fine again. When the code stopped *a* was 5 again.
Is this a bug or is this a behavior because of something I did?

Comment: I've experienced similar behavior in the debugger. It's most likley a bug.

Comment: I've had strange behaviour as well - sometimes it's been 3 lines out! Xcode 4 really is unacceptable - it crashes every time I try to do any SVN-related actions, and it even crashes when I reorganize files. And I paid £2.99 for this, so I feel compelled to use it! I just hope Xcode 4.1 is a whole lot better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion Xcode 4 is currently very, very broken. I know that doesn't really answer your question, but I've seen enough strange behaviour from the debugger to think that your situation is most likely a bug.